# explanation of regex rule

Tags: javascript, regex

I've inherited some code which validates a coupon.
The logic of this coupon is a regular expression rule verified with JS.
I don't have much experience with this, and will really appreciate if someone can help me understand it.

This is the rule:

```
theStr.match('^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{1}$')
```

Comment: It matches strings consisting of a lowercase letter, followed by three digits, followed by another lowercase letter. `^` and `$` ensure that the entire string matches, not just a part of it. For example, "a123b" would match, but "xa123by" would not.

Comment: Check out **Regex Buddy** - You will find it very useful for building and understanding regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site can be very helpful for explaining regexes: http://regex101.com/

In this case, that regex matches the following, in this order:

`beginning of a string/line`

`any lower case letter`

`repeated only once (no repetitions)`

`any digit`

`repeated exactly 3 times`

`any lower case letter`

`repeated only once`

`end of string/line`

This would match a string like `"b589n"`.

Comment: Also, `{1}` is redundant and can always be removed. Every token is matched exactly once unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 3):

Must start with a lowercase letter followed by three numbers and another lowercase letter. Also note that in JS you use `/regex/` not `'regex'`.

Answer (score 2):

Line starts with one lowercase letter a-z, followed by three digits, and ending with one lowercase letter a-z

The `^` symbol means "at the start of the line", the `$` symbol means "at the end of the line", the stuff in the []'s is the chars to match on, and the number in the {}'s is the number of times to repeat.